# How to find crowdtesting platform?

Tags: manual-testing, testcase, regression-testing

I worked for Testbirds on some tests, but they invite me to test really rarely. I have more free time, so would like to work more. Are there another crowdtesting platforms? Which ones have you tried?

Comment: This isn't really a good fit for this site - if you look at the help center (https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) there's a guide to asking questions that won't be closed as too broad or opinion-based. Please edit the question to ask for specific information like the advantages of other platforms or how to get more testing from your current platform.

Comment: Did you ask Testbirds what you could do to invite you more often? Maybe getting another device or something could help? I would ask them. This is another big one: https://www.utest.com/

Comment: I have used UserTesting.com.

Comment: "Are there another crowdtesting platforms?" https://www.google.com/#q=crowd+sourced+testing

Comment: @JoeStrazzere : Thanks, but I would like to get also some feedback about sites. Maybe "I used it and it is ok." or something similar experience.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at https://tester.test.io/ as well. Invitation are enough often (3-5 times a week).